# Javascript function wrapper fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to add functionality to a jQuery method.

I have the code

```
$('li.s').appendTo('#target');
```

There are multiple elements which match `li.s`, and I can see it's grabbed correctly using Firebug.

The `append` method works fine without my wrapper.  However, with my wrapper (which shouldn't change anything about the function):

```
var oldAppend = $.fn.append;

$.fn.append = function(expr) {
    return oldAppend.call(this, expr);
};
```

The correct jQuery object is returned, but only the first `li.s` is appended to `#target`, instead of all of them.  Why is this?  Where am I losing my other elements in the call to `oldAppend`?

Comment: If you console.log() the 'length' property of 'this' just before you return 'oldAppend.call(this, expr)' what is its value? :: console.log(this.length);

Comment: Your example shows you using "appendTo", but then you're wrapping "append"?

Comment: @great_llama, Yes, jQuery.appendTo calls jQuery.append.

Comment: @J-P, I tried that and I get 1. Hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you (I) are note passing *all* of the arguments sent to `append` by `appendTo`.  Use `apply` and `arguments` like so:

```
var oldAppend = $.fn.append;

$.fn.append = function() {
    return oldAppend.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

(Remember that all functions have `arguments`, so you need to `var args = arguments` in the proper scope to access those arguments, e.g. when using `$.each`.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't delved into the jQuery code to check this, but most functions should usually return this.each(fn):

```
$.fn.append = function(expr) {
    return this.each(function() {
        oldAppend.call($(this), expr);
    });
};
```

You'll notice I've had to wrap `this` in a jQuery object inside the inner function, as the append method expects that to be the context. I'm not sure, but you may find you need to wrap the outer reference to `this` as well:

```
return $(this).each
```

Comment: Still fails (same problem).  I had tried this myself, and just re-did it to make sure I didn't mess up the first time.